# Put Win10 drive in new achritecture. Seems to run fine, is it safe?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, migration

This might be a dublicate, I am not sure.

I had read that hard drive migration of the Win 10 install drive to a new machine with different hardware is possible with the retail ver sion of Win 10. I, luckily, have this version.

I "upgraded" my old PC, or rather the surroundings of my GPU since I swapped case, Mainboard, CPU and RAM. I moved from 1150 and DDR3 to AM4 with DDR4.

I bootet from the same drive I used in my old machine and I'm now writing this question using the new build, since rebuilding the old machine would take for ever.

Is it safe to just use windows as is?
Should I run specific tests? If so, which?

Or am I better of completely whiping C and settung up Win10 anew?

Comment: Migration to a new HDD is possible regardless of the edition of Windows you are using.  You will have to ask a specific question, "is it safe", is a subjective determination.  What exactly is your question?  You successfully migrated your installation to the new system, what are you worried about, be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine.

As long as it booted and can get the the internet, Windows 10 will pickup ***almost*** anything that it needs.

Check your device manager to make sure there are still drivers for everything you care about but aside from that you should be fine.